# Is Contexts.Context.Parameters deprecated in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Help me before I go on a rampage and tear the heads off all the stuffed bunnies in the house!!

I am simply trying to follow the MSDN [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) for creating a Windows Service in C#. Under the sub-section "Adding Startup Parameters", there is the following line of code:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = ...
```

When I type the symbol Parameters in that line, VS2013 (Premium) shows this error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Parameters'." When I check the Contexts.Context class in the Help Viewer, and in MSDN online, Context, indeed, does not have a Parameters property. Well, gee, I'm sure lots of people have tried to follow this walkthrough; did they all encounter this error?

I've googled for hours and *everything* I've found talks either about setting Context parameters, using Context Parameters, or both. I can find nothing that says Context.Parameters has been deprecated.

Comment: In response to the editing: I see my brand of humor isn't appreciated. I'll refrain in the future. But, you should know that all non-prepositions in a title have initial capital letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only occurrence of `Context.Parameters` that I can find on [that tutorial page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the following code snippet, in step 3 under "Adding startup parameters":

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    string parameter = "MySource1\" \"MyLogFile1";
    Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = "\"" + Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] + "\" \"" + parameter + "\"";
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
}
```

In this method, `Context` refers to the [Context property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.context(v=vs.110).aspx) that's inherited from the base [Installer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.Install.Installer(v=vs.110).aspx), not to [System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.contexts.context(v=vs.100).aspx).

Remove `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.` from your code and it should compile successfully.

Comment: Well, damn! I looked at this for at least two hours and never noticed the additional qualification. That's what I get for letting intelliSense run wild.

Comment: P.S. Really appreciate it.